# Taking medians from within a column vector using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have two column vectors.

The first column vector is several thousand data points long, and I need to take the median from the first forty items, and then the median from the next forty, and so on.

The second column vector contains a group ID (from 1 to 3).

My goal is to end up with a bunch of median calculations and to have them sorted by group. I am very unsure of how to go about this in MATLAB.

Comment: Explain what this group ID column vector does? Does it match your first vector element for element assigning a group to each element?

Comment: Your assumption is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a bit of code to get you started.

If you have both vectors in one named variable, and the number of columns is exactly divisible by 40, do this:

```
% column 1 = data, column 2 = groupID
test = rand(400,2);

% compute medians of data
medians = median( reshape(test(:,1), 40,[]) );

% make each entry correspond to the correct groupID
medians = repmat(medians, 40,1);
medians = medians(:);
```

If your data is NOT exactly divisible by 40, use a simple loop:

```
N = 40;

test = rand(10*N+4,2);

n = 1;
medians = zeros( ceil(size(test,1)/N), 1 );
for ii = 1:numel(medians)
    if n+N-1 > size(test,1)
        medians(ii) = median(test(n:end,1));
    else
        medians(ii) = median(test(n:n+N-1,1));
    end
    n = n+N;
end
```

and replicate as before if necessary.

Adjustments to this code for if you have the `groupID` in a separate variable, or how to sort these things according to `groupID`, are pretty straightforward.

Comment: That looks great! Could you please explain in relation to your first bit of code what the [] means?

Comment: Got it - unknown dimension.

Answer (score 3):

`reshape` your vector into a 40xN matrix, and then use `median` to take the median of each column.

Comment: This seems like an excellent answer but I am wondering then how I get my group IDs into this new matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the group is fairly easy:

```
groupIDvec = groupID(1:40:end);% A vector with group numbers
```

Finding the median of each group can be done as @Oli described, by using `reshape`

```
medianmat = reshape(datavector,40,[]); 
medianvec = median(medianmat);
```

Now you just need to sort them:

```
[groupIdvec,idx] = sort(groupIDvec)
```

And here is your sorted result, where groupIDvec indicates in which group each value is:

```
result = medianvec(idx);
```

I do not have Matlab at hand so it may contain errors, but it should be about ok.

Comment: Could you explain this bit? groupIDvec = groupID(1:40:end);

Comment: The syntax is as follows... `you start here`:`you take steps of this size`:`you end here` where 1 of course is the first element, and end can be used to indicate the last element. So with this you take every 40th element from your vector. Assuming each set of forty items has a group id, this is what you need.